# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, geckodriver

Firefox v77.0.1 64 bit 
python 3.6
geckodriver 0.26[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have been grappling with the same issue for a few hours now.